# Howto run FParsec in VS2013

Tags: parsing, exception, f#, visual-studio-2013, fparsec

How do I run FParsec in VS2013 Professional Edition?

I tryed to use the following nuget packages:

- http://www.nuget.org/packages/FParsec/
- http://www.nuget.org/packages/FParsec-Big-Data-Edition/

and I tried to compile the source-code of https://bitbucket.org/fparsec/main on my own and use the generated dlls: **FParsec.dll** and **FParsecCS.dll**.

But in either way I always get the following exception running the tutorial code:

```
System.MissingMethodException
Method not found: 
  Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<FParsec.CharStream`1<!!0>,FParsec.Reply`1<Double>> FParsec.CharParsers.pfloat()"
```

Can anyone provide a step-by-step solution who to get FParsec running on VS2013?

This is the code I try to run:

```
open FParsec

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
  let str s = pstring s // This line works
  let floatBetweenBrackets = str "[" >>. pfloat .>> str "]" // This line breaks
  Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
  0
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you said which tutorial code was failing, perhaps even provide a cut-down example that shows the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add App.config to your project with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Check your version of FSharp.Core and patch this snippet if necessary.

Comment: Thank you. That worked! Hint for all users with the same problem: You can the publicKeyToken of a dll with the following command:

`sn.exe -T "PathToDLL"`

The sn.exe-Tool resides at:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools`. Probably you have to edit this path.